# How to multiply two matrices in MPI using MPI_Scatter/MPI_Gather

Tags: mpi, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to **multiply two matrices** in C using **MPI** collective communications **MPI_Scatter** and **MPI_Gather**.

My code executes with correct result, but when I'm testing processes **after MPI_Scatter**, I'm **getting zeros on every process**.

So, I'm thinking there is some problem with **sendcount** and **recievecount** parameters in **MPI_Scatter** and **MPI_Gather** functions.

Thanks for helping :)

```
// matrix multiplication using MPI_Scatter/MPI_Gather

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define N 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a[N][N], b[N][N], c[N][N], r1, c1, r2, c2, i, j, k, rank, size;


  MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  // min number of processes must be 2
  if(size < 2){
    fprintf(stderr, "Number of processes must be min 2 for %s\n", argv[0]);
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
  }

  // if rank of process is zero, initialize matrix a and b
  if(rank == 0){
    printf("Insert number of rows and columns for matrix a: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &r1, &c1);

    printf("Insert number of rows and columns for matrix b: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&r2, &c2);

    // If the number of columns of matrix a isn't equal to the number of rows of matrix b
    // ask user to insert again number of rows and columns
    while (c1!=r2){
      printf("Error! number of columns of matrix a isn't equal to number of rows of matrix b\n\n");

      printf("Enter rows and column for matrix a: ");
      scanf("%d %d", &r1, &c1);

      printf("Enter rows and column for matrix b: ");
      scanf("%d %d",&r2, &c2);
    }

    // Enter elements of matrix a
    printf("\nEnter elements of matrix a:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < r1; ++i){
      for(j = 0; j < c1; ++j){
        printf("Enter elements of matrix a%d%d: ",i+1, j+1);
        scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
      }
    }

    // Enter elements of matrix b
    printf("\nEnter elements of matrix b:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < r2; ++i){
      for(j = 0; j < c2; ++j){
        printf("Enter elements of matrix b%d%d: ",i+1, j+1);
        scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }

  // send one row of matrix a to every process in the group    
  MPI_Scatter(a, N*N/size, MPI_INT, a, N*N/size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  MPI_Bcast(b, N*N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  for(i=0; i<r1; ++i){
    for(j=0; j<c2; ++j){
      // initialization of matrix c(result matrix)
        c[i][j]=0;
        for(k=0; k<c1; ++k)
          c[i][j]+= a[i][k]*b[k][j]; // multiplication of matrix a and matrix b, save result in matrix c
    }
  }

  MPI_Gather(c, N*N/size, MPI_INT, c, N*N/size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  // print result
  if(rank == 0){
    printf("\nResult of matrix multiplication:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < r1; ++i){
      for(j = 0; j < c2; ++j){
          printf("%d ", c[i][j]);
        if(j == c2-1){
          printf("\n\n");
        }
        }
    }
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: You don't even send `b` around. How do you even expect this to work?

Comment: MPI_Bcast(b, N*N, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); Is this OK

Comment: you do not scatter one **one** row but **some** rows, and depending on `size`, you might not even scatter entire row(s). Then you cannot access `a[0:r1-1][*]` since you previously scattered not **all** rows but **some** rows.

Comment: you cannot invoke collective operations with `sendbuffer == recvbuffer`, you have to use `MPI_IN_PLACE` instead.